# kuberntes ingress rewrite URL is not overwritten according to the regex rule

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have the following configuration for rewrite for user-service and it is supposed to remove either 'sso' or 'user' and use the rest of the path to redirect to the user-service

nginx-ingress-controller:0.32.0

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: user-service
  namespace: pre-prod
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: clusterissuer-selfsigned-default
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2/$4
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://example.com"
  labels:
    app: pre-prod
    component: user-service
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(user|sso)/(api|saml)(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: user-service
              servicePort: 80
```

The path /sso/api/auth/sso/signin is supposed to be converted into /api/auth/sso/signin but the backend sends the response

```
error: "Not Found"
message: "No message available"
path: "/sso/api/auth/sso/signin"
status: 404
timestamp: "2021-01-20T09:47:04.544+0000"
```

`172.18.240.0 - - [20/Jan/2021:09:47:04 +0000] "GET /sso/api/auth/sso/signin HTTP/1.1" 404 161 "https://example.com/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" 693 0.023 [pre-prod-user-service-80] [] 172.18.64.24:9090 166 0.022 404 a5844078b332b882056516aa50b0eb2b`

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You appear to have omitted the leading `nginx.` from [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite)

Comment: @mdaniel Thanks a lot! You saved the day!

Comment: @mdaniel can you post your solution as an answer? It will be visible for other community members.

Answer (score 2):

The annotation has a typo, in that it omitted the leading `nginx.` from [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite)